Voice Activity Detection (VAD) and noise cancellation in a voice recorder - Flutter WEB
I need help with implementing Voice Activity Detection (VAD) and noise cancellation in a voice recorder for the Flutter web platform. I have tried multiple solutions but haven't been able to get it working. Could you provide guidance on how to achieve this?
Using Pre-Trained Machine Learning Models (TensorFlow.js for VAD) and onnx model also useing but have not able to work
Expected Result :
Effective Voice Activity Detection (VAD) that accurately segments speech from background noise.
Reliable noise cancellation that removes most background noise, providing clear voice recordings across browsers
Actual Result:
Noise cancellation is not functioning effectively on the web platform.
i try this methods ..
link : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IEit83JhQjW5kxX1HevE2LFJbQcThUbI/edit
